# Any restrictions on calling ArcPy from non-Esri web service?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, arcgis-license-manager

I recently saw some success calling a python geoprocessing script from Node.js.  I was also thinking of using flask instead of an arcgis server geoprocessing service.

Does anybody know if there are restrictions on calling arcpy from non-esri web service from a license perspective?

***Disclaimer:** No advice will be interpreted as legal counsel, just looking for general knowledge.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [commented by @JasonScheirer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75499/arcgis-license-question-any-restrictions-on-calling-arcpy-from-non-esri-web-ser#comment103452_75499):

> In general, you will need an ArcGIS for Server license to talk to any
>   ArcGIS software across a network, including via a web service.